# A JavaScript error occurred in the main process. Uncaught exception: Error: Cannot find module '...\main'

Tags: visual-studio-code, error-handling

[image: warning screenshot]

When I try to open VS Code, this error sentences popped up.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling vs-code should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few issue tickets with similar error messages and circumstances:

- [A JavaScript error occurred in the main process #172039](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/172039). Problem caused by installing both a user installation and a system installation at the same time. Solved by uninstalling either one.
- [Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\main' #137303](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137303). Possibly caused by antivirus.
- [Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\main' #138893](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138893). Also possibly caused by antivirus corrupting the VS Code installation. Suggested to try uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code.